# Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

A misleading error message from the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering%
\subfloat[]{
    \label{subfig1}
    \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig1.pdf}%
}%
\qquad%
\subfloat[]{
    \label{subfig2}
    \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig2.pdf}
}%
\label{myfig}
\caption{A caption for figures \subref{subfig1} and \subref{subfig2}.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

gives

```
! Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.19 ...es \subref{subfig1} and \subref{subfig2}.}

?
```

What have I done wrong? I can't see any extra `}` anywhere.

Comment: You need to protect `\subref`, i.e. `\protect\subref{subfig1}`

Comment: Aah. I have no idea what [*fragile commands* and `protect`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands) are, but now I know where to begin. Thanks very much @karlkoeller!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The easiest solution in these cases is to add `\protect` in front of the usual suspects; `\subref` is one of them because it has a *-variant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\subfloat[]{%
    \label{subfig1}%
    \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig1.pdf}%
}%
\qquad
\subfloat[]{%
    \label{subfig2}%
    \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig2.pdf}%
}

\caption{A caption for figures \protect\subref{subfig1} and \protect\subref{subfig2}.}
\label{myfig}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note where I added/removed `%` at end of lines and the position of `\label{myfig}` *after* `\caption`.

This might be annoying if you have several appearances of `\subref` in moving arguments. In this case you can “robustify” the command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \robustify

\robustify{\subref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\subfloat[]{%
    \label{subfig1}%
    \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig1.pdf}%
}%
\qquad
\subfloat[]{%
    \label{subfig2}%
    \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig2.pdf}%
}

\caption{A caption for figures \subref{subfig1} and \subref{subfig2}.}
\label{myfig}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Another solution is to avoid `subfig` for `subcaption`, which is the path I'd recommend:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig1}}{%
    \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig1.pdf}%
}%
\qquad
\subcaptionbox{\label{subfig2}}{%
    \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig2.pdf}%
}

\caption{A caption for figures \subref{subfig1} and \subref{subfig2}.}
\label{myfig}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Can you explain why the `\qquad` line doesn't need a `%`?

Comment: @jozxyqk A space/end-of-line is ignored after a control sequence (whose name consists of letters).

Comment: The `\protect` method also solved my problem with an equivalent error using `inparaenum` inside a caption - had to apply it to `\begin`, `\end` and each `\item`

Comment: Another 'suspect' turned out to be the `\linebreak`. Using `\protect\linebreak` also helped.

Comment: Using `\protect` also solves problems caused by hyperlink in captions.

Comment: I had the same issue with `cref` from the `cleveref` package. Adding `\protect` sorted it. But I was _already_ using the `subcaption` package, _not_ `subfig`. Is this to be expected?

Comment: @SamOT The command `\subref` provided by `subcaption` is robust. Also `\cref` is; but it would be a different issue anyway.